# Need for a JasperReports null parameter value to show all

Tags: parameters, null, jasper-reports, option-type

I've been through this problem for a while and I hope you can help me.

I have a report made on iReport, and I'd like the report to be filled even if some parameters are null.

Here's what I have

```
SELECT
    evento."titulo" AS evento_titulo,
    evento."data_inicio_realizacao" AS evento_data_inicio_realizacao,
    evento."data_fim_realizacao" AS evento_data_fim_realizacao,
    evento."id" AS evento_id
FROM
    "public"."evento" evento
WHERE
    evento."id" = $P{eventoid} OR
    evento."data_inicio_realizacao" BETWEEN $P{data1} AND $P{data2}
```

I'd like the WHERE clause to be optional, i.e., if I leave these parameters null (or 0-valued on id's case), I want to get all values instead of a blank report.

Is it possible? I found some people making a $P{WHERE_CLAUSE} and passing the whole where clause as its value, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this instead of the dynamic sql you're doing now...

```
select xxx
from <table>
where $P{eventoid} is null or evento."id" = $P{eventoid}
```

Sorry for replying to such an old post...

Comment: Its never too late to reply to a post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Well I tried a bit harder and figured out how to make it work by passing the whole WHERE clause inside a $P{} param.

I simply deleted the whole WHERE clause and put this:

```
$P!{whereClause}
```

I put a single parameter in there and deleted the three parameters $P{eventoid}, $P{data1} and $P{data2} from the report.

I'm working on Spring MVC and inside my class Controller, under the POST request mapping for that page, I added a String variable called whereClause, and set its value to "WHERE 1=1" (or true if you prefer):

```
String whereClause = "WHERE 1=1";

if (relIndice.getEventoId() != 0) {
    whereClause += " AND evento.id = " + relIndice.getEventoId().toString();
}

if (relIndice.getData1() != null) {
    whereClause += " AND evento.data_inicio_realizacao >= '" + relIndice.getData1().toString() + "'";
}

if (relIndice.getData2() != null) {
whereClause += " AND evento.data_inicio_realizacao <= '" + relIndice.getData2().toString() + "'";
}

whereClause += " ORDER BY evento.data_inicio_realizacao";
```

After setting the initial value for the whereClause variable, I made 3 IF statements, each for one of the fields I want to include in the WHERE statement, in the SQL.

Since "WHERE 1=1 will run anyway, a blankspace is needed before the AND, in order to make a clean and working syntax.

And in the end I added an ORDER BY clause that will run anyway too.
And that's it, the values of your parameters will be the values you'll get from the getters you want to use.

In my case I can leave any values null or zero(on eventoId's case since it's an int), and I'll have all the records from that table since the SELECT statement won't see the WHERE clause... Coz it doesn't exist!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

> evento."data_inicio_realizacao"
>   BETWEEN $P{data1} AND $P{data2}

try replace for this

(
(evento."data_inicio_realizacao" >= $P{data1} or $P{data1} is null)
or
(evento."data_inicio_realizacao" <= $P{data2} or $P{data2} is null)
)